# How can I trigger previous commands from the VS Code task terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my question below, nx just happens to be the plugin launching the task terminal, but my question applies to any task command that is run in a special terminal in VS Code.

When I run an nx task via the nx plugin, it launches a special type of integrated terminal that runs the task command.

However, when I want to re-run that task command, I can't do it from the terminal since it is a special type of terminal. This is very frustrating because I have to jump back to the nx plugin in order to rerun the command instead of doing it directly from the terminal view.

How can I rerun the task command that was just run from the terminal?

I'm attaching an annotated screenshot here to show what the terminal looks like:

[image: annotated screenshot of the VS Code terminal]

Comment: When that is the active terminal, does this keybinding work:  `  {
    "key": "alt+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "echo ${env:APPDATA}"
    },
  }`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working for me Mark. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: When I have a regular terminal open then I do see "echo" getting printed to the terminal when I activate the keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workarounds from [Re-run Last Task
#25310](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25310):

- You can bind a keyboard shortcut to the task to make it easy to access via keyboard ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25310#issuecomment-297409112)). Ex.

  > ```json
  > {
  >   "key": "ctrl+h", // TODO pick a key
  >   "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  >   "args": "foo" // the task name
  >  }
  > ```
- Use the `Tasks: Rerun Last Task` command in the command palette ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25310)), and optionally bind that command to a keyboard shortcut to make it easier to access via keyboard.

You may be interested in this feature-request issue ticket: [Add a restart task button into the right-click menu of running task. #182248](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182248). Unfortunately, it [didn't get enough community support in time to get added to the backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182248#issuecomment-1633467724).

Note that if the task is a shell/process-type task (yes- I know this question is not about shell/process-type tasks), if you have shell integration on, there should be a button to re-run the command (see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153451, which added testing for this feature).

For your reference / learning purposes, this info was found by googling "`github vscode issues button rerun task`".